# How i can pass routes path from the array and update them on Click call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React JS. I am making a project in which I initially create an array of menu items to store some of the props of the menu like its state or path etc.

Now I want to implement a router function but now I cannot understand how I can implement that using the array and map function.
I tried something like `<Route path={getPath} > <MenuItem /> </Route>` but i dint get any result.Any way to solve this issue?

Required Functionality: When I click on any navbar link, the router takes me to that path and shows a specific component and also updates Menu State to true so that the user knows he is on that current page.

I am attaching the code below :

```
import React from 'react'
import Menu from './components/Menu'
import Logo from './components/Logo'
import LeftSide from '../src/components/LeftSide'
import About from './components/About'
import Projects from './components/Projects'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import { useState } from 'react'
import RightSide from './components/RightSide'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      menuItemName: 'Home',
      path: '/',
      menuItemState: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      menuItemName: 'About',
      path: '/about',
      menuItemState: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      menuItemName: 'Projects',
      path: '/projects',
      menuItemState: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      menuItemName: 'Contact',
      path: '/contact',
      menuItemState: false
    }
  ])

  // get menu path from menuItems on click
  const getMenuPath = (menuItem) => {
    setMenuItems(
      menuItems.map(item => {
        if (item.id === menuItem.id) {
          item.menuItemState = true
          return item.path;
        } else {
          item.menuItemState = false
        }
    }
      )
    )
  }

  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="relative flex lg:flex-row space-y-0 md:flex-col flex-col h-screen">
          <div className="flex flex-col space-y-24 md:space-y-30 lg:space-y-56 p-4 bg-[#1c1c1c] w-full">
            <Logo />
            <LeftSide />
            <div className='flex flex-row p-1'></div>
          </div>
          <div className="text-white bg-[#171717] p-4 w-full">
            <div className="flex flex-col lg:space-y-36 md:space-y-16 space-y-0 p-1 w-full">
              <div className="hidden md:hidden lg:block">
              <Menu menuItems={menuItems} onClick={getMenuPath}/>
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/about" exact component={<About />}/>
                  <Route path="/projects" exact component={<Projects />}/>
                  <Route path="/contact" exact component={<Contact />}/>
                </Switch>
              </div>
              <RightSide />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what your other files are doing, but if the function `getMenuPath` is supposed to actually return a path, it is not returning anything. Looks like this function is just calling `setMenuItems` and then not returning anything

Comment: Ok, thanks. Going to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

I see a couple of issues:

1. You are mutating the `menuItems` state in the `getMenuPath` callback handler.
2. The `getMenuPath` callback handler isn't dispatching any navigation action. If `Menu` isn't rendering `Link` components to effect a routing/navigation action then this code will need to issue an imperative navigation action.
3. The `react-router-dom@5` `Route` components take a reference to a React component on the `component` prop, not JSX.

## Solution

1. Fix the mutation by mapping the previous state to the next state, creating new object references for any state, *and nested state*, that is being updated.
2. If necessary, you'll need to move the `Router` component up the ReactTree so that the `App` component can use the `useHistory` hook and issue the imperative navigation action to the selected menu item path.
3. Use `component={Component}` instead of `component={<Component />}` for the `Route` components.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from './App';

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

...

```
import { Route, Link, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([....]);

  // get menu path from menuItems on click
  const getMenuPath = (menuItem) => {
    setMenuItems(menuItems => menuItems.map(item => ({
      ...item,                               // <-- shallow copy previous state
      menuItemState: item.id === menuItem.id // <-- update property
    })));
    history.push(menuItem.path);             // <-- issue imperative navigation
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="....">
        <div className="....">
          <Logo />
          <LeftSide />
          <div className='....'></div>
        </div>
        <div className="....">
          <div className="....">
            <div className="hidden md:hidden lg:block">
              <Menu menuItems={menuItems} onClick={getMenuPath}/>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
                <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
                <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
            <RightSide />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```